# Ruby convert array of hashes into one hash

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

The input hash array is something like this:

```
[{count: 111, date: A},{count: 222, date: B},{count: 333, date: C}]
```

I want convert it into:

```
{A => {count: 111}, B => {count: 222}, C => {count: 333}}
```

That's just a simplified version, the hash could be very large - I mean many keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
aoh = [{count: 111, date: 'A'},{count: 222, date: 'B'},{count: 333, date: 'C'}]
flat = Hash[aoh.map {|h| [h.delete(:date), h]}]
# => {"A"=>{:count=>111}, "B"=>{:count=>222}, "C"=>{:count=>333}}
```

This is simliar to @falsetru's solution, but slightly more general in that if there are more keys in the original hashes besides just `:count` and `:date`, they will all be preserved in the result:

```
aoh = [{count: 111, date: 'A', pos: 1},{count: 222, date: 'B', pos: 2},{count: 333, date: 'C', pos: 3}]
flat = Hash[aoh.map {|h| [h.delete(:date), h]}]
# => {"A"=>{:count=>111, :pos=>1}, "B"=>{:count=>222, :pos=>2}, "C"=>{:count=>333, :pos=>3}}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = [{count: 111, date: 'A'},{count: 222, date: 'B'},{count: 333, date: 'C'}]
Hash[a.map {|h| [h[:date], {count: h[:count]}]}]
# => {"A"=>{:count=>111}, "B"=>{:count=>222}, "C"=>{:count=>333}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `Array#inject` method is a good choice:

```
[{count: 111, date: 'A'},{count: 222, date: 'B'},{count: 333, date: 'C'}].inject({}) do |h, item|
  h[item[:date]] = {count: item[:count]}
  h
end
```